# Mesibo in angular 7 - conferencing local streaming is not working

Tags: mesibo

Mesibo group call is initiated.

`

```
publisher.call(o, 'video-publisher',function (p) {
        console.log('on_stream1111');
    }, function(p, status, video, q) {
      console.log('on_status');
    });
```

`

above publisher call is getting called without any errors, but On stream or on status callback is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your post. There are two versions of mesibo conference code here  https://github.com/mesibo/conferencing - which one are you using?

In general, if onstream is not called, you have a permission issue. getUserMedia requires https and hence you must run your code in a secure context with a valid certificate.

Try following code separately to see if you get media access

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true
})
```